# run await functions one after one

Tags: node.js, async-await

There are a lot of samples on running `Async/Await` functions. But only with one `await` call.

I don't find a right sample that I can run await functions one after one

```js
async function a() {
   console.log('this is function a');
   // do something
}
async function b() {
   console.log('this is function b');
   // do something
}
async function c() {
   console.log('this is function c');
   // do something
}

async function main() {

  await a();

  await b();

  await c();

}

main();
```

Test with above code (hide the real code), I found it is not guaranteed, function c will be executed last.

How can I adjust it?

Node version:

```
$ node --version
v10.15.3
```

Comment: Can you show an example where `c` is *not* executed last? It should always be initialized after the other two have initialized.

Comment: these functions are several hundred lines in it.

Comment: Please trim it down to a [MCVE] so that the question is on-topic and answerable

Comment: I adjusted a little bit, will this make sense for you? I am thinking to use `.then()`, but not looks good.

Comment: It always shows `a`, then `b`, then `c` for me

Comment: If you have hundreds line in each function, they are not executed one after one. They are running paralleled

Comment: The order is guaranteed in the code you showed. You'll have to examine your code more to find out why it's different from the code in your question (aside from just being more lines); and, if after determining the differences you still have a question; make an question with an example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @Bill the current code will execute perfectly in order, but we cannot say about your actual code without the lines, maybe put it on a gist and link it here or post it here.

Answer (score 1):

Like the comments on your question say: your example code will always run in the right order.

In the comments you mention that if there are hundreds of lines of code, it does not always run that way.

Could it be that somewhere in that code you use things like setTimeout()?

Since setTimeout runs in a separate execution context, the async/await will not wait for it to finish. I have updated your example to demonstrate this.

```js
async function a() {
  console.log('this is function a - 1');
 await getResponse();
  console.log('this is function a - 2');
}

async function b() {
   console.log('this is function b - 1');
   setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log('this is function b - 2')
   }, 500);
}
async function c() {
   console.log('this is function c');
}

async function main() {
  await a();
  await b();
  await c();
}

function getResponse() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
     console.log('setTimeout finished');
      resolve("Response from API. Executed after 5 secs");
    }, 500);
  });
}


main();
```